# char tab is setting tab[0] to 0

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, hex

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    std::string napis = "Inhibitor";
    int length = napis.length();
    char hex[256];

    std::cout << "Original: " << napis << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        char buffer[2];
        itoa(napis[i], buffer, 16);
        hex[2*i] = buffer[0];
        hex[2*i+1] = buffer[1];
    }
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length * 2 + 1; i++)
    {
        std::cout << hex[i];
    }
}
```

After all those operations I get that hex[0] == 0. Don't really know why. I am not setting this value anywhere I guess. Program is supposed to code string into hexadecimal.

Comment: What do you mean by coding a string into hexadecimal? ASCII values in hexadecimal?

Comment: yes, didn't know how to describe it ;/

Comment: Your `itoa()` call has a buffer overflow since it will output 2 hex digits AND a null terminator, but your `buffer[]` is too small for that. You don’t need `itoa()` at all, you can produce the `hex` string using simple math on the `napis` characters directly. Also, your `hex` string is not null terminated.

Comment: omg thats right, after changing buffer[2] to buffer[3] it works, i thought that itoa() was returning null terminator as a value not as a part of buffer[], thank you very much.
I know it can be done better in many ways. Rn it is just me playing with that so i can set everything and I will surely change many things underway.

Comment: What did you expect `hex[0]` to be. (Pretend you might not know how to accurately describe your goal, so that you might have to explicitly state the expected result in this case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`itoa`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/itoa-itow?view=msvc-160) function will write a terminating nul character into the buffer. In your code, this it will write 2 or 3 characters (depending in the ASCII value of the character in the string), which can exceed the array bounds.

The solution is to increase the size of `buffer` by at least 1:

```
char buffer[4];
```

Even better is to use the non-deprecated name (`_itoa`), which, in C++ with a character array, will call the safe version of the function ([`_itoa_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/itoa-s-itow-s?view=msvc-160)) which will detect buffer overruns.

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid the temporary buffer and write directly in the result buffer.

```
    char str[] {"abcdefg"};
    char hex[256];
    for (uint i {0}; i < sizeof(str) - 1; ++i) {
        ::sprintf (&hex[i*2], "%02X", str[i]);
    }
    std::cout << "Hex: " << hex << std::endl;
```